# How does iteration with each method over product of arrays work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like some help on clarifying how iteration over the product of arrays works in Ruby. After checking the documentation on *product* and *each* methods I wasn't able to find the answer.

I have two arrays:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Using the product method and specifying only one argument (*product*) to the *each* method:

```
arr.product(arr1).each do |product|
  p product
end
```

Prints:

```
# [1, "a"]
# [1, "b"]
# [1, "c"]
```

When passing two arguments (*number* and *letter*) to *each* method in this way:

```
arr.product(arr1).each do |number, letter|
  p number
  p letter
end
```

Results in the following output:

```
# 1
# "a"
# 1
# "b"
# 1
# "c"
# 2
# "a"
# 2
# "b"
# 2
# "c"
# 3
# "a"
# 3
# "b"
# 3
# "c"
```

Do I understand correctly that in the second case, Ruby iterates over each array (arr and arr1) which was supplied to the product method?

Comment: It would perhaps be more clear if you wrote `a = arr.product(arr1)` and then examine `a` before executing `a.each do |number, letter|; p number; p letter; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you for taking a look at it! I have now published this post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your block receives is always the same, a pair (a two elements array). In the second case you're basically destructuring the pair.

```
a = [1, 'a'] # a = [1, 'a']
a, b = [1, 'a'] # a = 1, b = 'a'
```

Comment: Ok, this clarifies it, I was able to find the concept of [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) in documentation.